# small range capacitor measurement

Tags: capacitor, capacitance

what is effect of capacitor on output voltage of op amp, **when we use capacitor on feedback loop**?
for example we can use lm358, with 2 resistor for gain (1K and 1K) we have gain=2, okay? **But what happened when we use capacitor exchange with resistor in feedback loop?**
[image]

Comment: What are series capacitors usually used for in AC circuits?  What about DC circuits?

Comment: The title is about capacitor measurement but the content is not.

Comment: You get an integrator

Answer (score 1):

> *But what happened when we use capacitor exchange with resistor in
> feedback loop?*

The op-amp will not be able to control the DC level fed back to the inverting input and, pretty soon, the output will force itself against one of the the power rails in a failed attempt to try and make the inverting input a virtual ground.